# C# - Importar arquivo de configuração (.ini)

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

Como eu importo um arquivo de configuração ini para que ele seja carregado e retorne com um valor de uma key:

Exemplo:

```
[version]
code=0.3
```

o programa vai carregar o arquivo ini e eu seleciono a seção (no caso é 'version'), seleciono a key(no caso é 'code') e a função / método retorna com o valor 0.3

Médoto:

```
var strCode = GetStringFromFile("atualiza.ini", "version", "code");
```

Estrutura do Arquivo (.ini):

```
[Seção]
Key=Value
```

Comment: Eu ouvir dizer que seria com o DLLImport e importa o User32.dll mas não faz diferença!

Comment: Faz mais sentido guardar as informações no `app.config`...

Comment: É uma exigência negocial que se importem os dados de um arquivo ini?

Comment: eu quero carregar o arquivo (.ini) de outro programa e ele só suporta o arquivo de configuração (.ini)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ideia em [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) e usar ficheiros de configuração XML, portanto, não existe uma forma nativa de ler os arquivos `.INI`.

Posto isso, e dado que por vezes as necessidades de negocio podem exigir o uso de um `.INI`, pode utilizar uma biblioteca de terceiros para ler/escrever:

- [Ini-Parser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/)

(Esta parte descaradamente tirada do [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file))

Pode ainda seguir um destes tutoriais que explicam como usar a DLL `kernel32` para ler e escrever um ficheiro `.INI`:

- http://jachman.wordpress.com/2006/09/11/how-to-access-ini-files-in-c-net/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C